# Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment ends with: property 'templateLink' doesn't exist

Tags: azure, arm-template

I'm using PowerShell toolkit for Azure and ARM Templates for XP1.

After running deployment command I get following error

```
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:36:03 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'templateLinkBase' at line '28' and column '30' is not valid: The language expression
    property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, available properties are 'template, parameters, mode, provisioningState'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
    At D:\Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates-master\Sitecore 8.2.3\xp0\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
    + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
    At D:\Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates-master\Sitecore 8.2.3\xp0\Sitecore Azure Toolkit 1.1\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:112 char:35
    + ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
    +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I followed steps from docs https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/82/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/deploy_a_new_sitecore_environment_to_azure_app_service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this post.
http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-azure-arm/

If you supply a ArmTemplatePath like c:\Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates\master\Sitecore 8.2.3\xm\azuredeploy.json to the ArmTemplateUrl parameter instead of a Url you get this error.

Answer (score 3):

You should upload your ARM templates and parameters to blob storage and make them available for the script.
Define parameter "templateLinkBase" in the parameters JSON file and provide the value for that which is the direct link to the container in your blob storage. For example:

```
"templateLinkBase": {
  "value": "https://ibuazurews.blob.core.windows.net/arm/"
},
```

Note: the URI should have a trailing slash.

In order to make it accessible for the script generate the SAS token for that container (for example using Azure Storage Explorer application) and put that SAS token into the parameter "templateLinkAccessToken" that should be also defined in the parameters JSON file.

So, as a result, you have 2 additional parameters in your parameters JSON file: one is defined above and the second one is for example:

```
"templateLinkAccessToken": {
      "value": "?st=2017-07-03T08%3A23%3A00Z&se=2017-07-04T08%3A23%3A00Z&sp=rwl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=c&sig=fj%2BhsmNYDBcYLcbRpcHkb794mHa9K5F3dElArsg05zg%3D"
}
```

And of course upload the ARM templates, "nested" and "addons" folders with their content to that container. See on the picture below.

[image]